# Unexpected node type error SequenceExpression with jest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I was adding a snapshot test to a piece of React code, and I incurred in this error: 
`Unexpected node type: SequenceExpression (This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error. Location has been estimated.)`

The code transpiles and works just fine, and the [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) doesn't warn me about anything.

Before this new test, no other test gave me any sort of similar error, and we have quite a few of them in our codebase.

I tried to reinstall `jest`, reinstall `babel-jest`, remove and reinstall all modules (using `yarn --pure-lock`), upgraded both `jest` and `babel-jest` to the latest version (*20.0.1* for both), rinsed and repeated.
Nothing worked.

This occurs only when I try to collect the coverage (with `--coverage`), while the minimal snippet it occurs with is:

```js
import { tint } from 'polished'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default styled.label`
  background: ${({ x, y }) => (x ? tint(0.3, y.a) : y.b)};
`
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what i've found:

This is an issue with jest code coverage being able to understand styled components and polished. I **am** using `babel-plugin-polished` with the following in my babelrc:

`"plugins": [ "polished" ]`

But still if you call `export` on a value, and do not also use that value in an object or exported object, it will fail.

Fails:

```
export const charcoalBlue = rgb(104, 131, 145);
```

Doesn't fail:

```
export const charcoalBlue = rgb(104, 131, 145);
const colors = { charcoalBlue }
```

So my solution has been to ignore my style files, or simply ensure I'm using the values I create and not just exporting them.

One way to ignore the style files, place this in your package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "!**/*.styles.js",
  ]
}
```

And name your style files `{ComponentName}.styles.js`

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I cannot separate styles from the rest of the code.
I'll do some tries using the exported variables, as suggested (maybe declare const, then export)!

Comment: Did either of you end up coming to another solution? I find that essentially integrating `istanbul` with `polished` is where this error begins to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue!

I fixed it by working around it:

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

styled.label`
  ${({x,y}) => x
    ? css`background: tint(0.3, y.a);`
    : css`background: ${y.b};`
  }
`;
```